# Android: Drawing to Canvas While in Loop

Tags: android, list, loops, android-canvas, draw

I'm playing around with Canvas to get the feel of it, so I created an array of Points that I then tried to draw to the Canvas. However, only the very last Point shows up on the canvas...
I'm not sure how to show all the points in the array on the canvas, but any help would be appreciated!

```
List<Point> pointList = new ArrayList<Point>();
Point point1 = new Point();
point1.set(0,0);

Point point2 = new Point();
point2.set(0,0);

Paint red = new Paint();
red.setColor(Color.RED);

for(int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
{
point1.set(i, i);
pointList.add(i, point1);

}

for(int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
{
point2 = pointList.get( i );        
canvas.drawPoint(point2.x, point2.y, red);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is in your set loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
{
  point1.set(i, i);
  pointList.add(i, point1);
}
```

In java, all variables containing objects are actually pointers.  Thus point1 always points to the same object, since you never change what it is pointing at.  On each loop iteration, you change the pointed to object, and re-insert it into the list.  Thus pointList contains 31 instances of the same point, all at (30, 30).

Instead, you should create a new point on each iteration, so your code looks like:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
{
  Point p = new Point();
  p.set(i, i);
  pointList.add(i, p);
}
```

Which will then create a new point on each iteration of the loop.  You also no longer need a point1 variable.

Also, you have your points very close together.  You may not be able to see the difference, even with those changes.  You may want to space your points out some.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because ArrayList add() is adding the reference to the object, not a copy of the object itself. Try:

```
List<Point> pointList = new ArrayList<Point>();
Point point1 = new Point();
point1.set(0,0);

Point point2 = new Point();
point2.set(0,0);

Paint red = new Paint();
red.setColor(Color.RED);

for(int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
{
    Point point3 = new Point();
    point3.set(i, i);
    pointList.add(i, point3);

}

for(int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
{
    point2 = pointList.get( i );        
    canvas.drawPoint(point2.x, point2.y, red);

}
```